# Make background image clickable

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage, with world map as background image for whole container.

In map, I have two countries colored RED and all other GREY.

Now, I want to give link to red colored area. So, when I click on Germany area in map, it should redirect me to www.something.de and when on Australia, www.something.com.au

I know mapping can not be used with background images.

Is there any other way to do this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a fully transparent `.png` and overlay it above the background image. Once done, just map it and you will get your desired result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice suggestion. But I can not use this in my case, b'se if I put image, the overall content will be shifted to bottom size.

Comment: Use `position` to make my solution work - @MilindBhatt